# Wordpress wpdb query issue - how to filter out revisions?

Tags: wordpress

Can someone tell me how to modify the code below so that it filters out revisions? I tried using revision deletion plugins but they only work for revisions of posts or pages... not custom post types.

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
global $post;

$review_id = $post->ID;

if (get_post_type($review_id) == "features") {
   $assoc_id = get_post_meta($review_id, "associated_hosts_value", true);
  $review_id = intval($assoc_id);
}

$assoc = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT post_id from wp_postmeta WHERE (meta_key='associated_hosts_value') AND ((meta_value LIKE ',{$review_id},%') OR (meta_value LIKE '%,{$review_id},%') OR (meta_value = '{$review_id}') OR (meta_value LIKE '%,{$review_id}'));");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revision is stored in `wp_posts` under the post_type column, so you will need to inner join on wp_posts and query for a `post_type NOT IN ('revision')`:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT post_id from {$wpdb->postmeta} INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} ON ID = post_id WHERE post_type NOT IN ('revision') ..."
```

By the way, inserting raw SQL queries in to get_col is a bad practice, as it leaves you vulnerable to SQL injections.  Use `$wpdb->prepare()` as shown here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

Note that you will need to escape the `%` used in the LIKE statements by changing them to `%%` to work within `prepare()`.

Also, you shouldn't hard code WP table names in to your query statements.  The wpdb class stores table names for use in constructing your queries, i.e. `$wpdb->posts`, `$wpdb->postmeta`.  Using these assures that your plugin will always query the correct WP tables.  Try your code in a multi site installation to find out why this is important.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I wish I could take full advantage of all your advice but I am totally new to mysql and wordpress db queries. I will try to make corrects based on your advise.

Comment: Hmm... Can I hire you to fix this? I've been trying to apply your advice to my specific code pasted above for a couple hours and gotten nowhere.

Comment: Wow, actually I got it but this isn't a problem I should have had in the first place. This happened because I used the plugin, Custom Post Type Switcher, to switch these from pages to "feature" post type before I used a "delete revisions" plugin to clear out all revisions... So there was basically 'revision' post meta attached to them, but not in the right place.